# Javascript escape double quotes twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems trying to display correctly the `value` of a text `input` field containing double quotes (").

Here is the code:

```
<script>
var locked;
function addHTML(html,id,replace){
    if(locked!=false){
        if(replace==true) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
        else document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML + html;
    }
}
</script>
<DIV id="divvalues">
    <div onclick='javascript:addHTML("<INPUT type=\"text\" id=\"inputvalues\" name=\"values\" value=\"Click on me, \"in double quotes\", click on me\" required size=53 />","divvalues",true); document.getElementById("inputvalues").focus();'>
        <span>Click on me, "in double quotes", click on me</span>
    </div>
</DIV>
```

As a result, only *Click on me,*  is displayed in the `input`.
Any idea on how I should escape the double quotes inside the `value` attribute?

Comment: Things would be a lot easier if you didn't use inline event handlers ;)

Comment: I don't know that the way you are doing it right now has a solution. Maybe try this plugin instead: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be easier for you to debug if you create a function in your script instead of doing everything in your onclick.

Instead I would start by doing something like this:

```
<div onclick='yourFunction()'>
```

And in your Javascript:

```
function yourFunction()
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The \"in double quotes\" is adding a " mark to you input tag.  Should they be "?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to move the HTML outside the `onclick` attribute and place it inside a Javascript `var`:

```
<script>
var locked;
function addHTML(html,id,replace){
    if(locked!=false){
        if(replace==true) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
        else document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML + html;
    }
}

var divvalueshtml = '<INPUT type="text" id="inputvalues" name="values" value="Click on me, &quot;in double quotes&quot;, click on me" required size=53 />';
</script>
<DIV id="divvalues">
    <div onclick='javascript:addHTML(divvalueshtml,"divvalues",true); document.getElementById("inputvalues").focus();'>
        <span>Click on me, "in double quotes", click on me</span>
    </div>
</DIV>
```